# Error in SQL syntax for INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table which contains 19 columns however not all the rows are being stored.

Only a few of the rows are being stored and I'm getting the error message:

> There is error in your SQL syntax.  Check your syntax for your SQL version.

Although when I echo the variables, they are working fine.

My code is as follows:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE tb(tb1 VARCHAR(50),tb2 VARCHAR(50),tb3 VARCHAR(100),tb4 VARCHAR(100),tb5 VARCHAR(100),tb6 
VARCHAR(100),tb7 VARCHAR(100),tb8 VARCHAR(100),tb9 VARCHAR(100),tb10 VARCHAR(100),tb11 VARCHAR(100),tb12 
VARCHAR(100),tb13 VARCHAR(100),tb14 VARCHAR(100),tb15 VARCHAR(100),tb16 VARCHAR(100),tb17 VARCHAR(100),tb18 
VARCHAR(100),tb19 VARCHAR(100))";

foreach ($xml->product as $character) 
{
    $a1=$character->category->primary;
    $b2=$character->category->secondary;
    $c3=$character->URl->product;
    $d4=$character->URL->productImage;
    $e5=$character->URL->buy; 
    $f6=$character->description->short;
    $g7=$character->description->long;
    $h8=$character->discount->amount;
    $i9=$character->discount->time;
    $j10=$character->price->sale;
    $k11=$character->price->retail;
    $l12=$character->brand;
    $m13=$character->shipping->cost->amount;
    $n14=$character->shipping->cost->currency;
    $o15=$character->shipping->information;
    $p16=$character->shipping->availability;
    $q17=$character->keywords;
    $r18=$character->upc;
    $s19=$character->m1;

    $sql="INSERT INTO tb
    (tb1,tb2,tb3,tb4,tb5,tb6,tb7,tb8,tb9,tb10,tb11,tb12,tb13,tb14,tb15,tb16,tb17,tb18,tb19) VALUES
    ('$a1','$b2','$c3','$d4','$e5','$f6','$g7','$h8','$i9','$j10','$k11','$l12','$m13','$n14','$o15','$p16','$q17','$r18','$s19')";
    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
}
```

Comment: Can you post what `$sql` is before the query gets executed?  There is *probably* a stray single quote somewhere

Comment: Or one of the variables is blank.

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated. You might want to consider switching to e.g. [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and whilst you're at it, using parameters.

Comment: @Andrew... Many variables are blank actually. How does it effect the sql database? I am extracting these variables from xmp files. Many nodes are blank in the file.

Comment: You never apparently created the table (no call to `mysql_query()` for it)... But this really suggests a design problem with your database. You should almost never need to create tables dynamically in your code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Except temporary tables, but even then it'd probably be better as a stored procedure ^_^

Comment: How to create table columns dynamically according to the xml file nodes? 
I searched a lot about it, couldnt find any way so have to create the table manually. And yes its a temporary table.

Comment: Using parameterised queries means that this ceases to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ANY of your values contains an apostrophe, your query breaks.

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` around each of your values as a quick fix.

A more correct and future-proof solution is to stop using `mysql_*` functions and instead start using PDO, making use of features like prepared statements as these take care of escaping things for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.  A frequent mistake with this type of query is that the number of fields does not match the number of values.  That is easier to troubleshoot if you type your query like this:

```
insert into table (
field1
, field2
, etc
)
values (
value1
, value2
, etc
)
```

This format makes it easier to count the number of fields and values.  Sometimes the problem is with a certain field or value.  This format, with the commas at the start of the line, make it easier to comment out blocks of code to isolate the problem.

Comment: It's easier still if you use `insert into table set field1=value1, field2=value2, ...`